# how to target the same element im styling in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ajax

I have a textarea element in React and I want to style it's height based on it's content.

I need to get an 'event' property to get the target and send it to a resize function I have,
it's possible to do on an 'onchange' listener, but I'm trying to do this in 'style'.

this is working:

```
onChange={e => resizeTextarea(e)}
```

but I'm struggling with this:

```
style={{height: this.scrollHeight}}
```

I have way more adjustments to do with the height(the logic is in the 'resizeTextarea' function),
but I have tried using scrollHeight just to see how to get the target element, and well, using 'this' or 'self' doesn't work, how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Use e.target instead of this.

Comment: The function is working inside of 'onChange' because it is targeting e.target inside.
The issue is that I don't have a way to use e.target in 'style', and so I can't target the element's properties

Comment: You can save the element's height/style as state property and then update it inside onChange. It would reflect in style once the state is updated.

Comment: I can't use state properties as the function is outside my component, I probably should have mentioned that now that I think about it.
Either way I got it working whenever it changes, but I need to figure out a way for it to update it's height as soon as I render it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback ref https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node:

```
<textarea ref={measuredRef}></textarea>
```

This is the measuredRef:

```
  const measuredRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.scrollHeight);
    }
  }, []);
```

I can set a div's height to textarea scrollHeight in this sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-elion-dosi8?file=/src/App.js:162-285

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! unfortunately it can't be the solution for me, because what I'm doing isn't inside the component :/
I have a function called 'generateNote' which generates multiple notes depending on an updating array, and each note has 2 phases, one in which it displays it's content, and one in which it becomes a textarea element. and when it does become a textarea element, I want it to extend to it's full height.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't quite get the right solution to my specific issue, but what I did is create a timeout with 0 seconds just as I create my textarea, and in it I target the textarea via it's id and send it to my resizing function, it's not the most elegant because it does flicker, but it's working and I'm totally fine with it.